# React Hooks: Can't send state from Child component to Parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a `<Day/>` component which renders a table full of times through the day.

[image: calendar and day component]

Right now I have a handleChange function in the `<TableLayout/>` which is listening for changes in the text-area.

```
function TableLayout({ sendEventTargetToParent }) {
  var [amountOfRows, setAmountOfRows] = useState(24);
  var [textValue, setTextValue] = useState('');
  var [eventName, setEventName] = useState('');

 useEffect(() => {
   sendDataToParent();
 }, [eventName, textValue]);

  function sendDataToParent() {
    sendEventTargetToParent(eventName, textValue);
  }

  function handleChange(event) {
    var { name, value } = event.target;
    setEventName(name);
    setTextValue(value);
  }
```

The markup:

```
  <TextArea
   rows={2}
   name="textarea"
   value={textValue}
   onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
   placeholder="Tell us more"
  />
```

I'd like to send that info from the text-area to the  component, you probably noticed already noticed the prop `TableLayout` is consuming:

```
 function TableLayout({ sendEventTargetToParent }) {
```

Which I thought belongs in useEffect because it's creating a side-effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  sendDataToParent();
}, [eventName, textValue]);

function sendDataToParent() {
  sendEventTargetToParent(eventName, textValue);
}
```

Anyway the idea is when those local variables/state change in `TableLayout` it gets kicked up to `Day`...

```
export default function Day({ dayInfo }) {
  var [dayInfoInChild, setDayInfoInChild] = useState({});
  var [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState('');
  var [timeOfDay, setTimeOfDay] = useState('');
  var [eventNameFromChild, setEventNameFromChild] = useState('');
  var [textValueFromChild, setTextValueFromChild] = useState('');

  function getEventTargetFromChild(eventName, textValue) {
    setEventNameFromChild(eventName);
    setTextValueFromChild(textValue);
  }

    useEffect(() => {
      if (dayInfo !== null) {
        var modifiedDayInfo = dayInfo
         .split(' ')
         .map((item) => {
           if (item.indexOf(',')) return item.replace(/,/g, '');
        })
         .join('-');

         setCurrentDate(modifiedDayInfo);

         if (localStorage.getItem(modifiedDayInfo)) {
           var stringVersionOfModifiedDayInfo = modifiedDayInfo;

           modifiedDayInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(modifiedDayInfo));

         if (!dayInfoInChild.hasOwnProperty(stringVersionOfModifiedDayInfo)) {
          setDayInfoInChild({
            ...dayInfoInChild,
            [stringVersionOfModifiedDayInfo]: modifiedDayInfo,
          });
        }

      } else {
        localStorage.setItem(modifiedDayInfo, JSON.stringify({}));
      }
        if (dayInfoInChild.hasOwnProperty(currentDate)) {
          setDayInfoInChild({
            ...dayInfoInChild,
            [currentDate]: {
              [eventNameFromChild]: textValueFromChild,
            },
          });
        }
      }
    }, []);
```

And the code in the `Day's`useEffect`essentially creates an JSON object in localstorage with its key based on the date if needed if not it pulls that key and object converts it to a JS object and puts it into the state using`useState`.

```
  var [eventNameFromChild, setEventNameFromChild] = useState('');
  var [textValueFromChild, setTextValueFromChild] = useState('');

  function getEventTargetFromChild(eventName, textValue) {
    setEventNameFromChild(eventName);
    setTextValueFromChild(textValue);
  }
```

this is the part where the state from the Child gets set in Day.

```
   if (dayInfoInChild.hasOwnProperty(currentDate)) {
     setDayInfoInChild({
       ...dayInfoInChild,
         [currentDate]: {
           [eventNameFromChild]: textValueFromChild,
         },
     });
  }
```

But right now I able to add one key stroke into the object and then the UI locks:

[image]

So how can I create a cohesive flow from my Child to the Parent using hooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By understanding your problem i suggest you to use `useContext`

Here is a link which can help you to solve this problem.

https://vimalselvam.com/post/react-hooks-lift-up-pass-down-state-using-usecontext-and-usereducer/

Comment: Thanks for referring my post. @antonio-pavicevac-ortiz, you will have to use the context api to pass the required state between components.